# Convert Lat/Long coordinate to ISN93

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone, gis

I need to change Latitude and Longitude to `ISN93`.

I am playing with GIS data that is in ISN93 format so I need to get the GPS stuff in same format.

Does anyone have any code that can do these conversions?

Comment: Do you need to convert these in a .NET application, or do you simply have a bunch of GPS data you need converted?  How easy this would be depends largely on what tools you have.  If, for example, you have your GPS data (assuming the WGS84 datum) in a PostGIS database, you could simply run a statement like `SELECT ST_Transform(geometry_column_name, 4659)`.  If you have a tool like ArcGIS, then you can use the reprojection capabilities that are built in.

Answer (score 2):

I made this Java code a few years ago which converts `ISN93` to The system used by GPS: `WGS84`.

https://github.com/Kjarni/StraetoRouteAPI/blob/master/java/ISN93_to_WGS84.java

```
package org.kjarni;

import android.graphics.PointF;

/*
 * Copyright (c) 2012, Gunnar Gu�var�arson, Gabr�el A. P�tursson
 * All rights reserved.
 * 
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *     * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *     * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *       documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *     * Neither the name of the <organization> nor the
 *       names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
 *       derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
 * 
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND
 * ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
 * WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
 * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL <COPYRIGHT HOLDER> BE LIABLE FOR ANY
 * DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
 * (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
 * LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
 * ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

/*
 * // example conversion:
 * PointF point = new PointF(359583, 406481);
 * ISN93_to_WGS84 converter = new ISN93_to_WGS84();
 * PointF result = converter.ISN93_WGS84(point);
 * label1.setText("x: " + result.x + " y: " + result.y);
 */

public class ISN93_to_WGS84
{
    private double a     = 6378137.0;
    private double f     = 1.0 / 298.257222101;
    private double lat1  = 64.25;
    private double lat2  = 65.75;
    private double latc  = 65.00;
    private double lonc  = 19.00;
    private double eps   = 0.00000000001;
    private double lat   = 0;
    private double delta = 1.0;

    private double rho, e, dum, sint, f2sin1, pol1, polc, peq;

    public ISN93_to_WGS84()
    {
        rho    = 45.0 / Math.atan2(1.0, 1.0);
        e      = Math.sqrt(f * (2 - f));
        dum    = f2(Math.sin(lat1 / rho)) - f2(Math.sin(lat2 / rho));
        sint   = 2 * (Math.log(fx(lat1)) - Math.log(fx(lat2))) / dum;
        f2sin1 = f2(Math.sin(lat1 / rho));
        pol1   = fx(lat1) / sint;
        polc   = f3(latc) + 500000.0;
        peq    = a * Math.cos(latc / rho) / (sint * Math.exp(sint * Math.log((45 - latc / 2) / rho)));
    }

    private double fx (double p)
    {
        return a * Math.cos(p / rho) / Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow(e * Math.sin(p / rho), 2));
    }

    private double f1 (double p)
    {
        return Math.log((1 - p) / (1 + p));
    }

    private double f2 (double p)
    {
        return f1(p) - e * f1(e * p);
    }

    private double f3 (double p)
    {
        return pol1 * Math.exp((f2(Math.sin(p / rho)) - f2sin1) * sint / 2);
    }

    public PointF ISN93_WGS84(PointF input)
    {
        double pol  = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(input.x - 500000, 2) + Math.pow(polc - input.y, 2));
        double lon  = 90 - 2 * rho * Math.atan(Math.exp(Math.log(pol / peq) / sint));
        double fact = rho * Math.cos(lon / rho) / sint / pol;

        while (Math.abs(delta) > eps)
        {
            delta = (f3(lon) - pol) * fact;
            lon += delta;
        }

        lat = -(lonc + rho * Math.atan((500000 - input.x) / (polc - input.y)) / sint);
        return new PointF((float)lat, (float)lon);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some javascript that converts WGS84 to ISN93:

https://gist.github.com/kristjanmik/6925cbefaa311145c58a

```
function WGS84_To_ISN93(l,m){
    l = parseFloat(l);
    m = parseFloat(m);
    var k=l*0.0174532925199433;
    var p=0.0818191913305*Math.sin(k);

    var o=11616778.382033*Math.pow(Math.tan(
        0.785398163397448-(k/2))/Math.pow(
        (1-p)/(1+p),0.04090959566525),0.90633380084752);

    var q=(m+19)*0.0158185089469038;
    return {
        x:Math.round((500000+o*Math.sin(q))*1000)/1000,
        y:Math.round((3482044.27322585-o*Math.cos(q))*1000)/1000
    };
}
```

Make sure to do a full battery of tests around this before you use it.  I haven't done a full analysis of this to be sure it's exactly right in all cases.  Let me know if you see any problems.